# Why is it in these two examples, one is redirecting to the correct URL while the other isn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, parameters

I have a destroy method within a notecards controller that I am calling from a users page to delete a notecard.  In the first example below.. the redirect is passing the notecard ID resulting in a page not found, while the second the user ID is being passed correctly finding the user page.. can someone help me understand why?

## Redirects to user passing id of notecard

```
def destroy
    @note = Notecard.find_by_id(params[:id])
    delete_note(@note)
    redirect_to user_path(@current_user)
end
```

## Redirects to user passing id of user

```
def destroy
   @note = current_user.notecards.find_by_id(params[:id])
   delete_note(@note)
 redirect_to user_path(@current_user)
end
```

Update:

Thanks for the responses.  The code is here: https://github.com/incorvia/plumnotes/.. The authentication is in the sessions helper and the sessions controller.  As for the log:

With Notecard.find_by_id(params[:id])

```
Started DELETE "/notecards/177" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-15 11:53:38 -0400
  Processing by NotecardsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"WctbONb/qAO+hesHZ6Yw5zU19eCPNGeILIhxnW9Pi1Y=",  "id"=>"177"}
  Notecard Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `notecards`.* FROM `notecards` WHERE `notecards`.`id` = 177 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM `notecards` WHERE `notecards`.`id` = 177
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/177
Completed 302 Found in 12ms


Started GET "/users/177" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-15 11:53:39 -0400
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"177"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 177 LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 14ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=177):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `show'

Rendered /Users/Kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@notes/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered /Users/Kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@notes/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/Kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@notes/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (4.6ms)
```

With current_user.notecards.find_by_id(params[:id])

```
Started DELETE "/notecards/179" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-15 11:56:18 -0400
  Processing by NotecardsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"WctbONb/qAO+hesHZ6Yw5zU19eCPNGeILIhxnW9Pi1Y=", "id"=>"179"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
  Notecard Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `notecards`.* FROM `notecards` WHERE `notecards`.`user_id` = 9 AND `notecards`.`id` = 179 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.9ms)  DELETE FROM `notecards` WHERE `notecards`.`id` = 179
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/9
Completed 302 Found in 95ms


Started GET "/users/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-15 11:56:18 -0400
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
```

Comment: Sounds like your `current_user` is not being defined correctly. You should be defining it only once during login and never any where else

Comment: Please update your question with two things: 1) Your current_user method, and 2) the console output for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that @current_user wasn't actually being defined for the @Notcard controller unless the current_user method was called. That's why that the current_user.notecards... worked
It also seems that with user_path(@current_user) .. if @current_user isn't defined then it just takes the id from the params.. which happens to be the notecard id and not a user id...
The solution to fixing it was to either user current_user.notecards.. or add a before_filter for the controller that authorizes users and defines the @current_user instance variable :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to guess what is defined to local var @current_user and where it occurs.
If you really interested, why, - probably more piece of code could be helpful.

Sometimes, keep it simple could be quite an interesting idea (:

```
redirect_to user_path( current_user.id )
```